# Fast.ai Course 2020: HTTPError: 401 Client Error: PermissionDenied for url

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

I am going through the fast.ai course (version 2020) and am currently in lesson 2.

When trying to use the azure key, I always get this error and I can't figure out what to do:

#To download images with Bing Image Search, sign up at Microsoft Azure for a free account. You will be given a key, which you can copy and enter in a cell as follows (replacing 'XXX' with your key and executing it):

```
key = os.environ.get('AZURE_SEARCH_KEY', 'XXX')
```

#Once you've set key, you can use search_images_bing. This function is provided by the small utils class included with the notebooks online. If you're not sure where a function is defined, you can just type it in your notebook to find out:

```
search_images_bing

results = search_images_bing(key, 'grizzly bear')
ims = results.attrgot('content_url')
len(ims)


HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-cddb73f3292e> in <module>()
----> 1 results = search_images_bing(key, 'grizzly bear')
      2 ims = results.attrgot('content_url')
      3 len(ims)
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/models.py in raise_for_status(self)
    939 
    940         if http_error_msg:
--> 941             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    942 
    943     def close(self):
HTTPError: 401 Client Error: PermissionDenied for url: 
https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/images/search? 
q=grizzly+bear&count=150&min_height=128&min_width=128
```

I am using Google Colab.

Maybe I have to add that I don't know what the key name is that I should replace the 'XXX' with. Jeremy Howard said that you would get one when signing up to Azure, but I didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This at first didn't work for me also, then I realized I needed to register for a different Bing Search service on Azure. Look for "Bing Search v7" in the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to obtain key you have to make your own account on Microsoft Azure
2. On search bar write "Bing Search v7" like DigV mentioned. Click on Bing Search v7 in Marketplace category.
3. Now you will be on "Create Bing Resource" page. You have to fill in form.
   Name: FastAiCourse
   Subscribtion: Azure subscribtion 1
   Pricing tier: 3 transactions per second
   Resource group: MyFolder
   Confirm and create.
4. Wait a moment until it is created, then go to menu on left hand side. Click on "All resources" and then click on the name you created -> "FastAiCourse".
5. Click on "Manage keys" and then copy one of two keys and paste it instead of XXX  in `key = os.environ.get('AZURE_SEARCH_KEY', 'XXX')` in your model.

!!! Do NOT use Cognitive Services for this task. Its dead end altought it looks quite similar in process.